# open or closed set of a product of sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty subsets of the interval $[0,2020]$, bounded from above. We now define a new set: $$C = \{ ab  \ | \ a\in A  \ \wedge \ b \in B  \}$$If $A$ and $B$ are closed, is $C$ also closed ? Prove or give a counterexample.

I think this statement is true because the only subsets of $\mathbb{R} \ $ I could think of that are closed are closed intervals, but how do I prove this ? I have tried proving this with the definition of a closed set but it's hard with this definition of the set $C$. I haven't had a course on topology yet so I would rather want an analysis aproach. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Note that $\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}\cup\{0\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$, but it is not an interval.

Comment: Singleton points are closed.  And unions of more than one closed intvervals are closed.  Also not sure why *if* the only closed sets you could think of were intervals you'd think this is *false*.  Wouldn't you think it were true. If $A=[2,3]$ and $B=[10,20]$ then $C=[20,60]$ is closed.

Comment: My bad, I editted the question !

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is true. Since $A$ and $B$ are closed and bounded, they are compact. So, $A\times B$ is compact. And $C$ is the image of $A\times B$ with respect to a continuous function (multiplication). Since $C$ is compact, it is closed.

Comment: Thank you ! But I don't know what compact means, do you have a proof based on the definition of a closed set ?

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if (and only if) it is closed and bounded. And it can be proved that the cartesian product of two compact sets is compact and that continuous functions map compact sets onto compact sets.